# Can the hazard function be defined on a continuous state

Tags: survival, conditional-probability, hazard

The hazard function is defined as the instantaneous failure rate or instantaneous hazard rate as $\Delta t$ tends to zero

$$
h(t)= \lim_{\Delta t \to 0}  \frac{R(t)-R(t+\Delta t)}{\Delta t * R(t)}
$$

But lets say I don't care about time, and I care about a continuous state $x$. Can I defined a hazard function on the state as

$$
h(x)= \lim_{\Delta x \to 0}  \frac{R(x)-R(x+\Delta x)}{\Delta x * R(x)}
$$

Note $R(t)$ or $R(x)$ are the survival functions accordingly.

**EDIT**

There is one point that has not been addressed here - which is the reason I have not accepted an answer. The Survival function is defined only in the interval $[0, \infty]$ but the random variable $X$ domain is $[-\infty, \infty]$.

Comment: Mathematically, as long as that limit exists, it's just fine.

Answer (score 1):

**Those are the exact same thing:** All you have done here is to replace the argument value in the function with an alternative symbol.  The mathematical content of both statements is exactly the same.  Remember that you need to avoid equivocating between a function (which is a mapping between a domain and range) and its value at a particular argument value.  If you are speaking properly about a function $R$ then there *are no separate functions* $R(t)$ and $R(x)$.  There is just a single function $R: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow [0,1]$ that takes on output values $R(t)$ and $R(x)$ at the respective argument values $t$ and $x$.

Comment: Yes I agree but I strictly see the hazard function in the time context. Is it not a useful measure for a continuous random variable?

Comment: Well of course it is.  The hazard rate of an exponential distribution, for example, is constant - a well-known and defining property of the exponential distribution.  Furthermore, the "hazard function" is just a mathematical expression: $f(x)/(1-F(x))$ for continuous variables.  It's a valid function whether $x$ indicates time or something else, like the probability that I eat another bite of turkey given I've already eaten $x$ bites of turkey (the turkey has already failed to survive.)